# Handling openURL: with Facebook and Google

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, oauth-2.0

user in my app can login using 2 services : Facebook or Google

everything works fine, however, in the :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation {
    ...
}
```

i should decide to call the Facebook callback or Google callback

if the user has the apps, its easy, than i decide by the sourceApplication
but when not (no native Facebook account linked in, no FB app, no GooglePlus app), it links to the browser :( and i dont know if it is comming from Facebook or Google

**is there a way how to decide what to call? like**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation {

    // how to decide?
    if (facebook) {

        return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];

    } else if (google) {

        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We don't need to Explicitly check the URL, the code below does it:

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation
{

    if ([GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) {
        return YES;
    }else if([FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication]){
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For Swift users, (The idea from user2144179)

Import below frameworks

```
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FacebookCore // (FBSDKCore's alternative for swift)
```

and in your delegate methods

```
// when your target is under iOS 9.0
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let isFBOpenUrl = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let isGoogleOpenUrl = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    if isFBOpenUrl { return true }
    if isGoogleOpenUrl { return true }
    return false
}
```

or you can use another 'open url:' method if your target is 9.0+. SDKs include a method for it also.

Firebase Reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Facebook Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/reference/classes/applicationdelegate.html

Answer (score 5):

You can Try the following :

```
if ([[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"<Your Google Bundle ID>"].location ==            NSNotFound)
{
    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed
    return wasHandled;
}
else
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
return YES;
```

Call the above method in

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
          openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation
```

in your `appDelegeate.m`

Basically what this is going to do is examine the url prefix and then call the google+ method if url prefix is ur google+ bundle id , and if not , it'll call the fb method .
Hope this helps

Comment: You could alternately test that the URL's scheme starts with "fb", which would make the code app ID independent.

Comment: Genius, I could not for the life of me figure out why only FB OR G+ was working, never both at the same time

Answer (score 5):

The method "application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:" is deprecated from iOS9. so now you can use like.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary *)options {
       // For Google sign in SDK
       if ([[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]) {
          return YES;
       // For Facebook SDK
       }else if ( [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                       annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]){
          return YES;
      //For Google plus SDK
      }else if ([GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                       sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                              annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]){
          return YES;
      }

     return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Swift version for iOS 9.0 and above of the accepted answer could be something like this:

```
import FacebookCore

[...]

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)) {
            return true
        } else if (ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

Try to handle the URL with each SDK, the first one that recognizes it ends execution returning true. If no SDK could handle the URL, return false.

I hope it helps someone,

Xavi

Answer (score 1):

This might be the easiest solution,

```
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKCoreKit

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url) {
        return true
    } else if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url) {
        return true
    } else if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        ) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for a Swift 4.2 version:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool 
{
    if (url.scheme?.hasPrefix("fb"))! {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    } 
    else
    {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                                 annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }           
}
```

Comment: Though it gives the solution for the answer. It would be good to explain the code

Comment: thats i belive wrong code, becasue both Google and Facebook handle the url in all cases... it should be conditional, like in the accepted answer

Comment: Added prefix check for a facebook URL

Answer (score 0):

You can just let either Google SDK or Facebook SDK attempt handling and if the SDK does not handle then allow the other SDK to try:

```
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        let handled: Bool = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)

        if handled { return handled }

        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}

//deprecated method iOS 8 and older
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let handled: Bool =  SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
                                                                   open: url,
                                                                   sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                   annotation: annotation)

    if handled { return handled }

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to use [`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a)

Comment: `canOpenURL` first of all, allows you to tell which apps are installed on the device. You can inspect the URL's prefix to figure out which service it came from. URLs for Facebook's app will start with `fb:`

Comment: @Idles remember that this is the callback method. If your app supports both facebook and google urls, ```canOpenUrl``` always returns ```YES``` for both. You're right that you can inspect the url, but usually a library has a handleURL: method that returns a boolean for you. You wouldn't have to bother yourself unless you want to do magic yourself.

Answer (score -4):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{


   if( [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                     annotation:annotation])
   {
       return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                     sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                            annotation:annotation];
   }
    else if([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation])
    {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation];
    }
    return NO;
}
```